# Divide by zero error in .xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

In my android application i created and xml file in \res\layout\admin.xml

the layouts i used in it are :

```
<ScrollView >
<LinearLayout >
<TableLayout>
.
.
Components
.
.
</TableLayout>
  <TableLayout>
.
.
Components
.
.
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

error

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2011-11-17 13:35:10.046
!MESSAGE admin_view_pin.xml: / by zero
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at android.widget.TableLayout.mutateColumnsWidth(TableLayout.java:579)
    at android.widget.TableLayout.shrinkAndStretchColumns(TableLayout.java:568)
    at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:466)
    at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:431)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10577)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4270)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10577)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1090)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:314)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10577)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4270)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10577)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4270)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10577)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4270)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10577)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:316)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:380)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1310)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1075)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:901)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.pageChange(LayoutEditor.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:2743)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1429)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

Please guide me how can i remove this error and also i want to know why this error occured ??

admin_view_pin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    style="@style/white_background_bl_aatharv">
    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogout" android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="Logout" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/button_bl" />
            <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                android:stretchColumns="*">
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView android:text="Select" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center" />
                    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/selectRadioGroup" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_datewise"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Date Wise" />
                            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_IDwise"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="ID Wise" />
                        </RadioGroup>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView android:text="MemberID" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center" />
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/txtMemberID"
                        android:layout_width="120dip" android:singleLine="true"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:enabled="false" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView android:text="From Date" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center" />
                    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <EditText android:id="@+id/startDate"
                            android:layout_width="120dip" android:singleLine="true"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:editable="false"
                            android:enabled="false" />
                        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/button_bl"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
                            android:id="@+id/btnStartDate" android:text="Set Date"
                            android:layout_gravity="center" android:enabled="false" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="To Date" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center" />
                    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <EditText android:id="@+id/endDate" android:layout_width="120dip"
                            android:singleLine="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:editable="false" android:enabled="false" />
                        <Button android:id="@+id/btnEndDate" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Set Date"
                            android:gravity="center" style="@style/button_bl"
                            android:layout_gravity="center" android:enabled="false" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView android:text="Package Type"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center" />
                    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spnPackageType"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView android:text="Status" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center" />
                    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spnStatus" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView android:text="Active Status"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center" />
                    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spnActStatus"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center">
                    <Button android:id="@+id/btnGetDetails"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Get Details" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        style="@style/button_bl" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
            <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" android:id="@+id/pinDetailsTable">
                <TableRow>
                    <!-- <TextView android:text="" android:padding="3dip" style="@style/text_subheader_wh" 
                        /> <TextView android:text="" android:padding="3dip" style="@style/text_subheader_wh" 
                        /> <TextView android:text="" android:padding="3dip" style="@style/text_subheader_wh" 
                        /> <TextView android:text="" android:padding="3dip" style="@style/text_subheader_wh" 
                        /> <TextView android:text="" android:padding="3dip" style="@style/text_subheader_wh" 
                        /> -->
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

When i remove `HorizontalScrollView` from the layout i get this error

Comment: post the whole code please seems nothing wrong here.

Comment: Provide the entire xml with your TableLayout please

Comment: How does it looks the admin_view_pin.xml xml? Can you please post more xml code here?

Comment: @Shruti please see this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965501/how-to-fix-arithmeticexception-error-in-android

if you have any solution for this please help me!!That question is  asked by me

Comment: Reported this bug on the bug tracker (again): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/125765292

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think its your 2nd table layout, which doesn't have any columns in it, yet you're trying to stretch them all.

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" android:id="@+id/pinDetailsTable">
                <TableRow>
                    <!-- <TextView android:text="" android:padding="3dip" style="@style/text_subheader_wh" 
                        /> <TextView android:text="" android:padding="3dip" style="@style/text_subheader_wh" 
                        /> <TextView android:text="" android:padding="3dip" style="@style/text_subheader_wh" 
                        /> <TextView android:text="" android:padding="3dip" style="@style/text_subheader_wh" 
                        /> <TextView android:text="" android:padding="3dip" style="@style/text_subheader_wh" 
                        /> -->
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
```

Comment: may be this was the issue coz by adding columns i didn't got any error.

Comment: android:stretchColumns="*" will make the table layout give as much space as possible to each column - the first pass in doing this (before adjusting columns which need more room than others) is probably to average the available space by the number of columns, something like: getWidth() / numColumns; which would result in a divide by 0 (which is an illegal operation) if there are no columns.

Comment: @Funk This was helped me also.@Shruti nice question

Answer (score -3):

try including this at the top of your whole file. it fixed the issue for me!

(without qoutes on the outside of the carrets)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```