# LayoutParams error ? dividebyzero

Tags: android, layout

```
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
     {
         /*TableLayout tl= (TableLayout) rootView1.findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
         TableRow tr=new TableRow(this.mContext);
         TextView tv=new TextView(this.mContext);
         tv.setText(Integer.toString(colSize));
         tr.addView(tv);
         tl.addView(tr);*/
         TableLayout tl= (TableLayout) rootView1.findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
         //TableRow[] tr=new TableRow[colSize%5];
         //TextView[] tv=new TextView[colSize];
         System.out.print(colSize);
         int limit=1;
         if(Integer.parseInt(desc1)==0)
         {
             for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
             {

                TableRow tr = new TableRow(mContext); 
                 tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                     while(limit<=colSize)
                     {
                        if(limit==colSize)
                        {
                             break;
                        }
                         else
                             if(limit%5==0)
                             {
                                 limit++;
                                 break;
                             }
                         TextView tv=(TextView) new TextView(mContext);
                         tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                         tv.setText(colVals[i]);
                         tr.addView(tv);
                         limit++;
                     }
                     tl.addView(tr,i);
             }
            }

     }
```

Error Log

```
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.widget.TableLayout.mutateColumnsWidth(TableLayout.java:587)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.widget.TableLayout.shrinkAndStretchColumns(TableLayout.java:576)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:474)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:439)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1451)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at        android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    01-13 06:41:10.767: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Whats wrong with the layout parameters? help?
The dividebyzero is the problem. 
Also wanted to know if i can give the same id name for textview and tablerow name for all the rows of the table ? its a jsoup program for scraping table tags and display the table data in a dynamically generated table in android.

Comment: by id name i mean, variable name in the program not in the xml file.

Comment: update: Removing the layoutparams line seemed to fix the problem?
However someone explain why the problem occured?

Comment: See [this link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19343) for a few reasons it may have happened.

Comment: @user3187750 this has already been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163940/divide-by-zero-error-in-xml-file

Comment: the source is:   `private void mutateColumnsWidth(SparseBooleanArray columns,
            boolean allColumns, int size, int totalWidth) {
        int skipped = 0;
        final int[] maxWidths = mMaxWidths;
        final int length = maxWidths.length;
        final int count = allColumns ? length : columns.size();
        final int totalExtraSpace = size - totalWidth;
        int extraSpace = totalExtraSpace / count;` <== likely count==0