# ArithmeticException: Divide by zero with table layout dynamically in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to display 14 columns of an SQLite database in a table layout dynamically at run time. I have tried lots of, but when I run the app it crashes and I'm getting ArithmeticException: divide by zero and error for mutateColumnsWidth.

Here is my Activity code:

```
SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c1 =sqlDatabase.rawQuery(performanceQuery , null);

int rows = c1.getCount();
Log.e("rows "," = " + rows);

int cols = c1.getColumnCount();
Log.e("cols "," = " + cols);

//Cursor c1 =db.rawQuery(query, null);
if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) 
{  
    Log.e("11111","11111");
    if (c1.moveToFirst())
    {   
        Log.e("222222","222222");
        // outer for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            // inner for loop
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setTextSize(18);
                // tv.setTextColor(010101);
                tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                tv.setText(c1.getString(j));

                String strText = tv.getText().toString().trim();
                System.out.println(" strText " + strText);

                row.addView(tv);
            }
            Log.e("3333333","3333333");
            c1.moveToNext();

            Log.e("4444444","4444444");
            table_layout.addView(row);
        }
    }
    sqlDatabase.close();
    c1.close();
    Log.e("55555555","55555555");
}
```

Here is .xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="5dp" >

   <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout_PerformanceReport"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTitle"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Log error Information:

```
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.TableLayout.mutateColumnsWidth(TableLayout.java:579)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.TableLayout.shrinkAndStretchColumns(TableLayout.java:568)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:466)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:431)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you show what is on line 579

Comment: @mapo , I can't find out where is the line 579.

Comment: 1. The values of cols and col are not 0 right?
The line 579 in TableLayout about 
`int extraSpace = totalExtraSpace / count;`

Comment: @kidnan : Yes right the col are not 0.

Comment: @kidnan: But where is the issue of table layout.

Comment: @kidnan1991 : Can you explain how to solve this ?

Comment: Sorry for late response (i'm working :P)
row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
You can try to change to TableRow.LayoutParams
See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965501/how-to-fix-arithmeticexception-error-in-android)

Comment: @kidnan : I have change but shows error at line =params.addView(tv); The method addView(TextView) is undefined for the type 
 TableRow.LayoutParams

Comment: @kidnan :  I have change like this = TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: @kidnan : Still not display table

Comment: Replace `row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`
by 
`row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Comment: still getting same error =E/AndroidRuntime(592):  at android.widget.TableLayout.mutateColumnsWidth(TableLayout.java:579)

Comment: @kidnan : please help me I m fade up this problem ?

Comment: [see here](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/02/android-building-tablelayout-at-runtime.html)
It looks like your code.

Comment: @jvd Sorry, when I ran these code, it raises same problem.
Here, you should put in your table_layout  adding view (after log 44444), due to addView has another parameter, that is layout  params. Let me know if this error still occurs because i have just tested it on my emulator, and it's OK
`table_layout.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar error and couldn't find the problem as the logcat is not very informative.
In my case, it had to do with the fact that I was adding an empty TableRow.

```
  for (int i = from; i < until; i++) {
                TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                table.addView(row); 
              //ading views to the table row
                 ....

    }
```

But, before adding the views, another Exception was preventing the views from being added to the TableRow. I fixed that and the problem dissapeared.