# java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero in clearing table

Tags: android, logcat

I am trying to clear table by following code :

```
int count = table_layout_acc_statement.getChildCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    View child = table_layout_acc_statement.getChildAt(i);
                    if (child instanceof TableRow) ((ViewGroup) child).removeAllViews();
```

But I am getting the following exception :

```
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072): Process: com.era.customeragentapp, PID: 14072
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.widget.TableLayout.mutateColumnsWidth(TableLayout.java:587)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.widget.TableLayout.shrinkAndStretchColumns(TableLayout.java:576)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:474)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:439)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16848)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onMeasure(HorizontalScrollView.java:329)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16848)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16848)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16848)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16848)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2368)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16848)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2246)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1312)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1509)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
05-09 15:53:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 15:53:09.402: E/(14376): appName=com.era.customeragentapp, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
05-09 15:53:09.402: E/(14376): 0
05-09 15:53:09.402: E/(14376): appName=com.era.customeragentapp, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
05-09 15:53:09.402: E/(14376): 0
```

Why am I getting this error ? How can I solve this error ?

Comment: these exception bcoz of the Arithmetic operation .....

Comment: try to add exception. and find where it's occur. then easily find out the problem

Comment: I can not find where the error resides .

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/w9m7ANxx6KRExrA4CF7Suq .Here is my full code

Comment: Did you try deleting the rows in reverse order, from count to 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsut call `table.removeAllViews();`

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTable);       
table.removeAllViews();
```

Answer (score 0):

I will write this answer even if you did not give your layout yet but I guess you have use the strechColumn on it.

Something tell me you could read this ;)

[how to fix ArithmeticException error in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965501/how-to-fix-arithmeticexception-error-in-android)

And you can find the explanation here

[Divide by zero error in .xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163940/divide-by-zero-error-in-xml-file)

To make it short, an empty TableLayout with strechable column seem to crash...