# divide by zero while dynamically add the column in Table layout in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to add 15 columns dynamically in table.I'm getting ArithmeticException:divide by zero and tablelayout.mutateColumnsWidth.When i run the app it crashes.
Please can someone  help me please. Thanks to appreciate.

Log Error Info

```
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.TableLayout.mutateColumnsWidth(TableLayout.java:579)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.TableLayout.shrinkAndStretchColumns(TableLayout.java:568)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:466)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:431)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-11 12:58:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Print my all val in Log cat After this I'm getting Exception .

```
07-11 17:37:36.213: E/rows(410):  = 1
07-11 17:37:36.213: E/cols(410):  = 5
07-11 17:37:36.213: E/11111(410): 11111
07-11 17:37:36.213: E/222222(410): 222222
07-11 17:37:36.223: I/System.out(410):  strText drhgft
07-11 17:37:36.223: I/System.out(410):  strText 2014
07-11 17:37:36.223: I/System.out(410):  strText 
07-11 17:37:36.223: I/System.out(410):  strText 3.8
07-11 17:37:36.234: I/System.out(410):  strText 
07-11 17:37:36.234: E/3333333(410): 3333333
07-11 17:37:36.244: E/4444444(410): 4444444
07-11 17:37:36.244: E/55555555(410): 55555555
```

This is my Full class source code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.performance_report);
        table_layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout_PerformanceReport);
        BuildTable();


    }

    private void BuildTable()
    {  
String performanceQuery ="select performer_name,year" 
                +","
                +"(case when second_date='June' then ((performance_rate_one+performance_rate_two+performance_rate_three+performance_rate_four+performance_rate_five)/5) end) June"
                +","
                +"(case when second_date='July' then ((performance_rate_one+performance_rate_two+performance_rate_three+performance_rate_four+performance_rate_five)/5) end) July"
                +","
                +"(case when second_date='August' then ((performance_rate_one+performance_rate_two+performance_rate_three+performance_rate_four+performance_rate_five)/5) end) August"
                +" from performance"
                +" group by empid"
                +" order by empid";

        SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c1 =sqlDatabase.rawQuery(performanceQuery , null);

          int rows = c1.getCount();
          Log.e("rows "," = " + rows);

          int cols = c1.getColumnCount();
          Log.e("cols "," = " + cols);

        if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) 
        {  
            Log.e("11111","11111");
            if (c1.moveToFirst())
            {   
                Log.e("222222","222222");
                // outer for loop
                  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
                  {

                      TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    // inner for loop
                       for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                       {
                           TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                            tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                            tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

                            tv.setText(c1.getString(j));

                            String strText = tv.getText().toString().trim();
                            System.out.println(" strText " + strText);

                            row.addView(tv);

 }
                       Log.e("3333333","3333333");
                       c1.moveToNext();

                       Log.e("4444444","4444444");



                     table_layout.addView(row);


                  }
                  sqlDatabase.close();
                    c1.close();
                    Log.e("55555555","55555555");
            }

        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Please post ur logcat also... so that we can be more specific?

Comment: @Mann : i have post my log cat error.

Comment: TableLayout has to have at least one child. Add in xml TableRow with visibile=gone. Add dynamically new TableRows and delete first row.

Comment: once check the Log.e("xxx","xxx"); after which statement you are not getting exception

Comment: @LMK : Thanks for the reply , Sorry but I didn't get you.

Comment: @LMK : Log.e("55555555","55555555"); After this I , getting exception.Print the all values in log cat but table not display it crashes.

Comment: @jvd could you update full class source code

Comment: @LMK: I have updates my full class source code above.

Comment: @jvd see this post might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163940/divide-by-zero-error-in-xml-file

Comment: @LMK : Still getting same error.

Comment: remove  row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); and try

Answer (score 6):

Check your `LayoutParams` type, if you put your views into `TableRow`, you should use `TableRow.LayoutParams`, use `TableLayout.LayoutParams` when put into `TableLayout`.